# smbclient copy file with single quote

Tags: linux, samba, libsmbclient

how can i use single quote in smbclient "put" command?

For example:

```
smbclient -c 'put "/mydir/video.avi" "\Music\Guns N' Roses\video.avi"'
```

The ' in "Guns N' Roses" generate an error, but i cannot use "Guns N\' Roses", because will change path.

Comment: This question isn't about Samba or libsmbclient, it's about how to use quotes in your shell. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your shell doesn't allow use of escaped single quotes inside a single-quoted string. Read the section entitled "QUOTING" in `man bash` (assuming your shell is bash).

You need to escape the inner single quotes *outside* the single-quoted string:

```
smbclient -c 'put "/mydir/video.avi" "\Music\Guns N'\'' Roses\video.avi"'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
smbclient -c 'put "/mydir/video.avi" "\Music\Guns N'"'"' Roses\video.avi"'
```

Or alternately, you could put things in variables, use formatting, etc. Obviously I haven't tested this in your environment, but the following seems reasonable to me:

```
$ source="/mydir/video.avi"
$ target="\Music\Guns N' Roses\video.avi"
$ cmd='put "$s" "$s"'
$ smbclient -c "$(printf "$cmd" "$source" "$target")"
```